# Git is showing files that already exist as new files

Tags: git, github

I have trouble understanding git but I'll try to explain my problem as best as I can understand it.

I have a Folder with a Git repo in it, on the same level as .git/ folder is src/ folder. I have a repo on GitHub that also has src/ as a top level folder. These two folders have the same structure.

I ran `git remote add origin [remote]` and it worked. I then ran `git add src/` to track it. Then I ran `git status` but it showed in green `new file:` for every file inside src/.

What I expected to happen, and what I want, is to only detect changes based on the remote repository. If I change a file in my local repo, I want it to only show that file as edited so that I can commit it. Instead, while I have the correct origin remote for the remote repo, it shows all the files in my local repo that I copied from the remote one as new files.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

You messed up with some basics of Git.

`git remote add origin` just records "where to push / pull", no network operations will be taken.

`git add` and `git status` are all local operations, they just compare your working directory with **local** Git repository.

For "download" / "sync" the remote to your local repository, you should

```
git fetch origin master # this will download all commits from remote to local
# then the local branch "origin/master" will have the information of remote's master branch
git merge origin/master # this will merge "origin/master" to local master
# then the local repository is successfully "recovered"
# you can do a git status to see if they are already clean
```

Comment: But I thought my local repository would see those files as not new since they are on my disk?

Do I have a local origin/master that I need to update or something?

Comment: @Wolfie_Waffle As of my understanding for your operations, what you actually need is to "sync" Git history from remote only. Then my answer is for that.

Comment: First question, they are new to Git, because currently your local master is actually empty. You didn't have any commits at local master after those operations. Second question, you are expected to have a local master history, which should be synced from local origin/master from remote master.